# Traffic getting routed through Apache

Tags: centos, routing, apache-httpd

For some reason, certain outgoing traffic on my server gets routed to the Apache webserver I am running. this problem just started happening. I have the webserver set up to use vhosts, the webserver config hasn't been changed for probably a month.

If I try to open a connection to say google.com (note there is no www in the address), the page that shows is the default page for my webserver (meaning the site doesn't have a vhost). If I would have used www.google.com, it would show the expected Google homepage.

I don't know why this started happening; it is really weird. Running CentOS 6.3 x64

I see the default page for my webserver if I use the webserver as a socks proxy for my computer at home. I just downloaded vnc and firefox on the server and tried navigating on there, it goes to the default webserver page too. If I use wget, it gets the proper page from the real Google website. Other processes on the server that try to open a connection to google.com (as well as other websites) show up in Apache log files as well. From the machine, I can ping google.com and get the proper IP address it maps to.

Comment: Have you changed anything related to DNS recently?  For example, do you have the wildcard *.yourdomain.com referring to your webserver, and have 'search yourdomain.com' in your /etc/resolve.conf on your client?

Comment: i haven't changed anything recently related to dns or the webserver. the webserver runs a few websites, all with different domains. i dont have a search directive in /etc/resolv.conf (i never really understood what it does)

Comment: If you run `curl http://google.com` (or `wget ...` on the command line, does it go to your web server?  Can you narrow it down to it being your browser alone?

Comment: i added a paragraph to the end of original post with more information on when it occurs and when it doesnt

Comment: It sounds like you didn't intentionally setup your system to proxy, but yet it is. Were you hijacked? Am I reading this wrong?

Comment: i wasn't hijacked that i know of, but i really can't explain how this is happening. but yes, you are reading it right. i want to say that i noticed this stuff happening like a day after using yum to update the kernel to 2.6.32-279.2.1.. i don't know what i should be looking for, iptables doesn't have anything that would cause weird routing either..

Comment: This is CentOS 6.3? Have you activated gpg-checking of all packages?

Comment: Yes CentOS 6.3, all repos have gpg-checking except for the offical nginx repo, which hasn't updated/installed anything since Jul 10. Didn't know the nginx repo didn't have gpgcheck enabled, but it does now.